# Number of occurences of the digit 1 in a sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Michael's hobby is to calculate how many times the digit 1 appears in a consecutive sequence of numbers, starting with 1 and finishing with a number from a friend. For instance, if Sandra tells him number 1, Michael's answer will be 1. If Julia tells him 2, his answer will be 1, and if Alex tells him 12 his answer will be 5. Which is the first number divisible with 10, different to 0, that Jack should tell Michael, for the answer of Michael to be identical to the number told by Jack?

Comment: I tried to find a formula to resolve this, but I really don't know. Please help!

Comment: http://oeis.org/A094798

Comment: You could look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47200/number-of-digits-in-a-series-of-numbers) for ideas.

Comment: Is there a reason to think that your condition will ever occur?

Comment: my bf made a program and the program gave me number 200000 as an answer.

Comment: @paw88789:  not a guarantee, but it does.  Small numbers have many fewer $1$s than numbers.  Large numbers have many more $1$s than numbers because most of them have at least two $1$s.  There will be a transition.  It could be that you jump from deficit to excess.  In fact there are quite a few transitions where the numbers match.

Comment: @dletzner:  that is not the smallest.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Yes, I see, thanks!

Comment: @paw88789:  in fact there are exactly $84$ of them.  The last one, $1111111110$, ends in $0$.  This is a point we could have jumped from deficit to excess, but we happened to land exactly right.

Answer (score 2):

Values of $n$ where there are $n\ 1$s used to write the numbers up to $n$ are given in [OEIS A014778](http://oeis.org/A014778).  The lowest that is a multiple of $10$ is $199990$

Comment: to answer OP's question in the comments, "I tried to find a formula to resolve this, but I really don't know", how did you know to look in OEIS? Did you start with the sequence A094798 and follow the link to A014778? You couldn't really google for A014778 without (almost) solving the problem.